# creating a mailing list using SQL Server as the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am tasked with creating an Email DL where managers can subscribe and unsubscribe at there convenience.  In this type of a set up I am thinking that I will need a few tables.

```
Manager Table (first name, last name, email address)

dl1 (email address)
dl2 (email address)
dl3 (email address)
```

what I will like created is the manager will subscribe and the main manager table will house all the email addresses.  During the subscription process the managers will then have the opportunity to decide on which DLs there will like to receive communications from (dl1, dl2, dl3, etc).

I have access to SQLServer 2014 and will be using it for this project.  Any kind of help will be appreciated.  I am hoping that one of you kind folks can start me going and I can add / modify the DLs as needed.

Thanks in advance for any help / assistance you can provide.

Comment: A database holds data but does not offer any kind of user interface. From your description it seems you possibly need a master manager table (consider tying this to Active Directory rather than going off and building another "data silo" with a list of people in it). You also need a master "DL" (what is a DL please explain?) and another table that holds the managers that subscribe to that DL. Nowadays these things aren't built from scratch, you just find a cloud solution or do something like RSS feeds.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  In this case is DL is just an email distribution list.  We send out many different types of reports to many different distribution lists (DL) and maintaining these the current way it's being done is a nightmare.  What we are trying to do as mentioned is to somewhat simplify the process by having the managers the ability to subscribe to what they need and unsubscribe to what they don't need.  This was our email distribution lists are cleaner and only the managers who are subscribed to each list will receive the communication they subscribed to.

Comment: So you're sending reports to people. All enterprise reporting systems (IBM Cognos, SSRS etc.) have built in email list capability. How are generating the reports? If you were to build a custom email list program, what would be your preferred front end for maintenance? Web? Thick client? SQL Statements?

Comment: yes we custom build all of of reports from various systems using excel.  We currently use excel to house the various email distribution lists. When we generate the report when also generate the email as well from Excel which will call the email lists.  This does work for us the issue really is manually updating these email lists and keeping them up to date.  I was thinking if it was possible to have these lists maintain in SQL then link to them from Excel.  In terms of a front end having the Managers be able to use a web browser to subscribe or unsubscribe with SQL being the back end.

Comment: Have you considered using some kind of email contact group for this? You create a group email address (in outlook this would be a contact group). You email the report to the contact group. Managers are added or removed from these groups. The only downside would be it's not straightforward for managers to add and remove themselves. Is that the only reason you could think of that you wouldn't use a contact group or are there other reasons?

Comment: There would be one contact group per report. Think about what doesn't work for you in a 'contact group' solution and your existing Excel solution because any issue you currently have should be described and addressed in your new solution.

Comment: And seriously if you have the opportunity take a look at SQL Server Reporting Services which comes with SQL Server 2014 and consider moving all your Excel reports into it

Comment: yes pre office 365 this was ok for us as we (the department) controlled it - post office 365 it's out IT and the sizes of our email DLs are not practical for them to maintain on the fly for us.  Creating groups in outlook means that we still have to manually maintain and update often times on a daily basis.  In my mind  just though it was have been inherently better and more efficient having the managers self subscribe to which communication they want to receive.

Comment: So the main issue you are addressing is allowing managers to add and remove themselves from distribution lists rather than going through IT? Anyway I will post an answer to the database side of things.

Comment: Yes that is the main issue at this point dealing with IT and trying to have them maintain our numerous lists.  As it stands right now it takes almost 3 days to add, remove or modify a name on any of our numerous list going through IT.  I will certainly investigate the SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: I feel your pain. Today I raised 2 tickets and I could actually do what I need before I even get a ticket number back. Anyway. Just keep in mind that any IT related solution you come up with is going to run into the wall of IT at some stage.

Comment: Also have a bit of a dig around github and bitbucket. I'm sure someone will have already built something along these lines on there. You're just looking for a free open source web solution to manage lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I suggest the following tables:

This table holds your distribution lists, and information about them like the owner of the list, a description and a report name

- DistributionList
- Recipient
- DistributionListMember

Here are those tables in more detail:

### DistributionList

```
DistributionList_ID    INT   IDENTITY(1,1)
Name                 VARCHAR(100)
Owner                VARCHAR(100)
Description          VARCHAR(100)
ReportName           VARCHAR(100)
```

Additional useful fields in this table would be

- Last time the record was updated
- Last time a report was sent out against this list

Also this assumes one report per Distribution List. If you have many reports in a list or reports that are in many lists, you need to make this more complicated (for starters you need a master report list)

This table holds the list of users and their emails

### Recipient

```
Recipient_ID                 INT  IDENTITY(1,1)
WindowsLogon                 VARCHAR(100) 
EmailAddress                 VARCHAR(100)
SubscriberName               VARCHAR(100)
```

I assume this information is already in Active Directory. It's always a bad idea creating duplicated information silos that reflect data that already exists but I guess you're already doing that in Excel

This table holds the list of people subscribing to a list:

### DistributionListMember

```
DistributionListRecipient_ID    INT   IDENTITY(1,1)
DistributionList_ID             INT   (Foreign key to DistributionList table)
Recipient_ID                    INT   (Foreign key to Recipient table)
```

So there you go - a sample schema that holds data that you're after.

Creating a web application that references this is another story.

Comment: thanks for all your help and explanations.  I will build the tables and go from there.  Once I get a good foundation going then I think I'll be able to get the needed help to get the front end going.  Again much appreciated your efforts and advice.